# Convert the same page to PDF

Tags: php, laravel

I want to convert the same document to PDF or I want to add post method in url just like:

```
$dompdf->loadHtml($_POST['name']);
```

Here is the code:

```
<?php
// include autoloader
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();

$dompdf->loadHtml(file_get_contents('http://localhost/));

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper(array(0,0,850,2250), 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
//$dompdf->stream();

// Output the generated PDF (1 = download and 0 = preview)
$dompdf->stream("codex",array("Attachment"=>0));
?>
```

Comment: Right, so what is the problem?

Comment: Do you see the missing single quote? The color coding tells you there is a problem

Comment: no there's not any problem, i can create a PDF using this URL but i want to add Post method here so i can add url from HTML here

Comment: So go ahead and make a form that you can input a parameter from

Comment: i've already created a form but how i can add $_POST['name'] here?

Comment: You already answered your own question. Although it depends on what you are entering in the `name` field

Comment: coz it's laravel, and i'm not familier with laravel

Comment: i can use simple PHP here? coz it's laravel ?

Comment: Oh in that case can I suggest you go and [**Read The Manual**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/quick)

Comment: Thanx man ^.^ Done, solved my problem

Answer (score -3):

You're missing single quote in line if file_get_contents

```
<?php
// include autoloader
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();

$dompdf->loadHtml(file_get_contents('http://localhost/'));

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper(array(0,0,850,2250), 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
//$dompdf->stream();

// Output the generated PDF (1 = download and 0 = preview)
$dompdf->stream("codex",array("Attachment"=>0));
?>
```

Comment: Already mentioned in a comment. This does not actually attempt to answer the question!

Comment: Before comment, I started typing the answer and posted after comment. BTW if you noticed the quote is missing, will it work? Absolutely no. And if I'm correcting it, there is no point to downvote it. I'm making the answer to move in correct direction.

Comment: ___Sentence 2:___ This does not attempt to answer the question as asked

Comment: The code sample in the question is just the snippet of application. You never know if the form is ready, only the missing quote is creating problem. Downvoting simply discourages the attempt to answer.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.